Photonic clock and diagonal path (again)
I did went through some answers on here and reddit about this question and got some interesting insights about what could be going on but still no answer totally solved the question for me.
So, considering a vessel going half the speed of light relative to an observer, a photon is emitted in a photonic clock on the vessel. People in there would see a vertical movement of the photon but the guy outside would see light go in zig-zag.
This made sense to me the moment I understood that the guy outside may be considered as the one moving as things are relative. So he would see light moving diagonally because of his own speed.
But yet, how does light "decides" to agree (by going straight) with one point of view instead of the other ?
What links light to the spaceship ? Couldn't light decide to agree with the guy outside and show a zig-zag pattern to the ones in the spaceship ?
I know some of you are pretty good in the field so please be kind and help me find sleep again :)

Light doesn't get to decide anything. It does its thing, and relativity says what that looks like to people on different world lines.

@JonCuster :  At this point, we don't even need relativity.  Simple geometry is what tells us what the path looks like to different observers.  But of course your point remains.

Yet another post assuming that things in physics are somehow sentient. Please do not use informal language like "decides" and "agree". Unless a rigorous mathematical or physical definition is supplied, such terms are meaningless. As such this is a poor question.

@VincentThacker I don't assume things are sentient. Hence the quotes... I just find it hard sometimes to wrap my head around the fact that things are indeed completely relative. Excuse my stupidity but the other answers are way more useful.

Let's take an extreme scenario. You build a humongous light clock that has a height the length of half a light year. That's approximately $4.73\times10^{12} \text{ km}$. You're in your inertial spaceship, in flat space, far from any gravitational influence and you start your clock. According to modern physics, you will receive the first light signal back after exactly $1$ year.
Now, a curious alien is moving along in his own inertial spaceship, in the same direction as you do and at some relative speed with respect to you. He's looking at this weird device the human had built. What does he see? There's simply only one option. If in your frame the light signal went from one end of the light clock to the other, and returned to the same point, these events will also take place from the perspective of the alien. The difference is, the alien sees light taking a longer path, indeed a diagonal one. As an aside, since the speed of light is the same in all inertial frames, the alien has to wait longer than a year to witness the light coming back to you.
Now, our alien is very curious indeed, and he reasons as follows: "this inertial creature, has shot a light beam perpendicular to his line of motion and yet it is moving in this weird fashion. On the one hand, it is moving diagonally, but on the other it always remains exactly in front of the human creature. Why is that? Is there something special about shooting a light beam in that particular direction, perhaps?".
So, he decides to do his own experiment, build a similar clock, orient it the same way, and shoot his own light beam. Result? You must have guessed by now: the light beam comes back after one year and the alien thinks: "Well that's kind of silly of me to think anything else could happen, I shot the beam straight into flat space, and it just reflected back from that mirror in the other end. I should have realized, the inertial human experienced exactly the same thing in his own frame, but we're in relative inertial motion, leading to me seeing* his light taking a diagonal path".
The moral of the story: light has no preferred reference frame, it will behave exactly the same in every inertial reference frame. That's one of the two basic postulates of special relativity. The light clock is just a useful example to demonstrate some consequences of these postulates, but it is not really of fundamental significance because, it turns out that just as a light clock will appear to tick slower in a moving frame, so will an atomic clock, a cuckoo clock, and any other clock you can think of. It is indeed time itself that dilates in such a situation.
 * How one "sees" light moving inside the light clock is a separate issue, for theoretical purposes it is not important, I just thought it's worth mentioning that this is not obvious when thinking about "light clocks" in general. 


But yet, how does light "decides" to agree (by going straight) with one point of view instead of the other ?

Light doesn’t decide anything. It simply follows Maxwell’s equations.
Different frames are simply different descriptions of the same thing. The light just behaves the way it behaves. One point of view describes it one way and another describes it differently. But the two descriptions are describing the same thing.
An analogy is if you are on opposite sides of a race track and I say the racers are running to my right and you say the racers are running to your left. The racers aren’t deciding to agree or disagree with either of us. They are just running. And my description of their running is just as valid as yours.

What links light to the spaceship ? Couldn't light decide to agree with the guy outside and show a zig-zag pattern to the ones in the spaceship ?

Sure, just put the light source at an angle in the ship. That would change what the light is doing and so both descriptions would change accordingly.

The light goes wherever you point it. If you point the light vertically in either frame it follows a diagonal path in the other. The same applies if I climb a ladder vertically in one frame, I move diagonally in the other.
